# Send a login request (username and password) to a radius server (localhost port 1812)

Tags: node.js, radius-protocol

Does anyone knows how to send a login request (username and password) to a radius server (localhost port 1812) in nodejs ?
I dont know where to start.

Comment: [node-radius](https://github.com/retailnext/node-radius) may be a start.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)